# Run rails app in development mode forever

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Will it be any issues if I let my app in development mode forever? It works fine like that and if I change to production mode it gives some errors and I don't have the time or expertise to solve them.

So, if I make some adjustments to the development mode (like allow caching etc) will it run slower than in production? There will be additional issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noticed, there are things like caching which are disabled in development mode.

Checking out the config environment files (and docs and source code) should reveal more.

But you should probably try to figure out the production issues. Database configuration and migrations could be part of this, depending on the particular errors you're seeing.

Comment: yes, it fails on migrating the database. I wondered if it is something 'unchangeable' in the production mode compared to development mode..

Comment: first try running in production mode with same database that you have in development environment(database.yml).. does it work fine.. ?

Comment: finally, I managed to solve it. there was a missing table. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One more problem is when you get error messages they will be logged but not rendered to the user, instead the static error page from your public directory will be used in case of production environment.

If you getting error in migration then create a empty database using development environment and after creating database with development mode use it as production database. This will easily solve your problem.